# Is it possible with Apache to run a different version of PHP in a specific directory on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, apache

I need to be able to run a different version of PHP for all code under a specific directory.  This is Apache 2.4 running on a Windows system.

In my conf I currently have

```
LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
```

as well as

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

What I am looking for is

https://domain/ = PHP 7.3

https://domain/oldstuff = PHP 5.6

I found a page that said its as easy as adding a line to your .htaccess but I am not sure where I would define which version is which.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
```

Most of the examples I have found are for cgi or for linux and don't seem like they would help

Comment: https://www.dionysopoulos.me/apache-mysql-php-server-on-windows-with-multiple-simultaneous-php-versions/, https://steemit.com/cn/@jinzo/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-with-apache-on-windows, https://codebriefly.com/how-to-handle-multiple-php-versions-with-apache-server-on-windows/

Comment: _“Most of the examples I have found are for cgi”_ – that’s what you will have to use, multiple different PHP versions as Apache modules are not possible.

Comment: So would it be possible to use CGI for a specific directory and the module for the rest?